# How to fit known values to a known curve by changing x-axis

Tags: r, data-fitting

This is a continuum to a Cross-validated question where [I asked about plausible methods](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78359/fitting-two-sets-of-values-by-changing-x-axis) for the problem. This question is more programming orientated, so I post it here on SO.

## Background

I have a curve with known dates spanning over a year. The y-values of this curve are predictions for [d18O values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9418O) calculated from daily temperature and salinity records. I also have measured d18O values from a shell consisting of [calcium carbonate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_carbonate). These values are measured along distance axis, where the first and the last measurement takes place approximately (but not exactly) at the same time than the beginning and the end of the curve.

It is known that d18O values match with the predicted values in the curve within some unknown random error. I want to get the best fit for the measured values to the curve by changing the x-axis for the measured values (or at least by matching the index with the index in the curve). In this way I can get estimates for the dates of the measured values and can further estimate the growth rate for the shell over the year. The growth rate is expected to be variable and there might be a growth hiatus (i.e. the growth stops). However, the **growth between the measured values has to be > 0** (a constraint).

## Example data

Here are the example datasets (`curve` and `meas`ured):

```
meas <- structure(list(index = 1:10, distance = c(0.1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 
13, 20, 22, 25), value = c(3.5, 4.2, 4.5, 4.4, 4.7, 4.8, 5.1, 
4.9, 4.1, 3.7)), .Names = c("index", "distance", "value"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -10L))   

curve <- structure(list(date = structure(c(15218, 15219, 15220, 15221, 
15222, 15223, 15224, 15225, 15226, 15227, 15228, 15229, 15230, 
15231, 15232, 15233, 15234, 15235, 15236, 15237, 15238, 15239, 
15240, 15241, 15242, 15243, 15244, 15245, 15246, 15247, 15248, 
15249, 15250, 15251, 15252, 15253, 15254, 15255, 15256, 15257, 
15258, 15259, 15260, 15261, 15262, 15263, 15264, 15265, 15266, 
15267, 15268, 15269, 15270, 15271, 15272, 15273, 15274, 15275, 
15276, 15277, 15278, 15279, 15280, 15281, 15282, 15283, 15284, 
15285, 15286, 15287, 15288, 15289, 15290, 15291, 15292, 15293, 
15294, 15295, 15296, 15297, 15298, 15299, 15300, 15301, 15302, 
15303, 15304, 15305, 15306, 15307, 15308, 15309, 15310, 15311, 
15312, 15313, 15314, 15315, 15316, 15317, 15318, 15319, 15320, 
15321, 15322, 15323, 15324, 15325, 15326, 15327, 15328, 15329, 
15330, 15331, 15332, 15333, 15334, 15335, 15336, 15337, 15338, 
15339, 15340, 15341, 15342, 15343, 15344, 15345, 15346, 15347, 
15348, 15349, 15350, 15351, 15352, 15353, 15354, 15355, 15356, 
15357, 15358, 15359, 15360, 15361, 15362, 15363, 15364, 15365, 
15366, 15367, 15368, 15369, 15370, 15371, 15372, 15373, 15374, 
15375, 15376, 15377, 15378, 15379, 15380, 15381, 15382, 15383, 
15384, 15385, 15386, 15387, 15388, 15389, 15390, 15391, 15392, 
15393, 15394, 15395, 15396, 15397, 15398, 15399, 15400, 15401, 
15402, 15403, 15404, 15405, 15406, 15407, 15408, 15409, 15410, 
15411, 15412, 15413, 15414, 15415, 15416, 15417, 15418, 15419, 
15420, 15421, 15422, 15423, 15424, 15425, 15426, 15427, 15428, 
15429, 15430, 15431, 15432, 15433, 15434, 15435, 15436, 15437, 
15438, 15439, 15440, 15441, 15442, 15443, 15444, 15445, 15446, 
15447, 15448, 15449, 15450, 15451, 15452, 15453, 15454, 15455, 
15456, 15457, 15458, 15459, 15460, 15461, 15462, 15463, 15464, 
15465, 15466, 15467, 15468, 15469, 15470, 15471, 15472, 15473, 
15474, 15475, 15476, 15477, 15478, 15479, 15480, 15481, 15482, 
15483, 15484, 15485, 15486, 15487, 15488, 15489, 15490, 15491, 
15492, 15493, 15494, 15495, 15496, 15497, 15498, 15499, 15500, 
15501, 15502, 15503, 15504, 15505, 15506, 15507, 15508, 15509, 
15510, 15511, 15512, 15513, 15514, 15515, 15516, 15517, 15518, 
15519, 15520, 15521, 15522, 15523, 15524, 15525, 15526, 15527, 
15528, 15529, 15530, 15531, 15532, 15533, 15534, 15535, 15536, 
15537, 15538, 15539, 15540, 15541, 15542, 15543, 15544, 15545, 
15546, 15547, 15548, 15549, 15550, 15551, 15552, 15553, 15554, 
15555, 15556, 15557, 15558, 15559, 15560, 15561, 15562, 15563, 
15564, 15565, 15566, 15567, 15568, 15569, 15570, 15571, 15572, 
15573, 15574, 15575, 15576, 15577, 15578, 15579, 15580, 15581, 
15582, 15583, 15584), class = "Date"), index = 1:367, value = c(3.33, 
3.35, 3.36, 3.38, 3.4, 3.42, 3.43, 3.45, 3.47, 3.48, 3.5, 3.52, 
3.53, 3.55, 3.56, 3.58, 3.6, 3.61, 3.63, 3.64, 3.66, 3.67, 3.69, 
3.7, 3.72, 3.73, 3.75, 3.76, 3.78, 3.79, 3.81, 3.82, 3.83, 3.85, 
3.86, 3.88, 3.89, 3.9, 3.92, 3.93, 3.94, 3.96, 3.97, 3.98, 3.99, 
4.01, 4.02, 4.03, 4.04, 4.06, 4.07, 4.08, 4.09, 4.1, 4.11, 4.13, 
4.14, 4.15, 4.16, 4.17, 4.18, 4.19, 4.2, 4.21, 4.22, 4.23, 4.24, 
4.25, 4.26, 4.27, 4.28, 4.28, 4.29, 4.3, 4.31, 4.32, 4.33, 4.33, 
4.34, 4.35, 4.36, 4.36, 4.37, 4.38, 4.38, 4.39, 4.4, 4.41, 4.41, 
4.42, 4.42, 4.43, 4.44, 4.44, 4.45, 4.45, 4.46, 4.46, 4.47, 4.47, 
4.47, 4.48, 4.48, 4.49, 4.49, 4.49, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.51, 4.51, 
4.51, 4.52, 4.52, 4.53, 4.53, 4.53, 4.54, 4.54, 4.54, 4.55, 4.55, 
4.56, 4.57, 4.57, 4.58, 4.58, 4.59, 4.6, 4.61, 4.61, 4.62, 4.63, 
4.64, 4.64, 4.65, 4.66, 4.67, 4.67, 4.68, 4.69, 4.7, 4.7, 4.71, 
4.72, 4.72, 4.73, 4.74, 4.74, 4.75, 4.75, 4.75, 4.76, 4.76, 4.76, 
4.76, 4.76, 4.76, 4.76, 4.76, 4.76, 4.75, 4.75, 4.75, 4.75, 4.74, 
4.74, 4.73, 4.73, 4.73, 4.72, 4.72, 4.72, 4.71, 4.71, 4.71, 4.71, 
4.7, 4.7, 4.7, 4.71, 4.71, 4.71, 4.71, 4.72, 4.72, 4.73, 4.74, 
4.75, 4.75, 4.76, 4.78, 4.79, 4.8, 4.81, 4.82, 4.83, 4.84, 4.85, 
4.86, 4.88, 4.89, 4.9, 4.91, 4.92, 4.92, 4.93, 4.94, 4.95, 4.95, 
4.95, 4.96, 4.96, 4.96, 4.96, 4.96, 4.95, 4.95, 4.95, 4.94, 4.93, 
4.92, 4.92, 4.91, 4.9, 4.89, 4.88, 4.87, 4.86, 4.85, 4.84, 4.83, 
4.82, 4.8, 4.79, 4.78, 4.77, 4.76, 4.75, 4.75, 4.74, 4.73, 4.72, 
4.72, 4.71, 4.71, 4.71, 4.7, 4.7, 4.7, 4.7, 4.7, 4.7, 4.7, 4.7, 
4.7, 4.7, 4.7, 4.7, 4.7, 4.69, 4.69, 4.69, 4.69, 4.69, 4.69, 
4.69, 4.69, 4.68, 4.68, 4.68, 4.67, 4.67, 4.67, 4.66, 4.65, 4.65, 
4.64, 4.63, 4.62, 4.61, 4.6, 4.59, 4.58, 4.57, 4.56, 4.55, 4.54, 
4.53, 4.51, 4.5, 4.49, 4.48, 4.47, 4.46, 4.45, 4.43, 4.42, 4.41, 
4.4, 4.39, 4.38, 4.37, 4.36, 4.35, 4.34, 4.33, 4.32, 4.32, 4.31, 
4.3, 4.29, 4.28, 4.28, 4.27, 4.26, 4.25, 4.24, 4.24, 4.23, 4.22, 
4.21, 4.21, 4.2, 4.19, 4.18, 4.17, 4.17, 4.16, 4.15, 4.14, 4.14, 
4.13, 4.12, 4.12, 4.11, 4.1, 4.09, 4.08, 4.08, 4.07, 4.06, 4.05, 
4.05, 4.04, 4.03, 4.02, 4.02, 4.01, 4, 4, 3.99, 3.98, 3.97, 3.97, 
3.96, 3.95, 3.94, 3.94, 3.93, 3.92, 3.92, 3.91, 3.9, 3.9, 3.89, 
3.88)), .Names = c("date", "index", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 
-367L), class = "data.frame")
```

...and here is how it looks like:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(gridExtra)

p.curve <- ggplot() + geom_line(data = curve, aes(x = date, y = value)) + scale_x_date(name = "Month", breaks = date_breaks("months"), labels = date_format("%b")) + labs(title = "curve")
p.meas <- ggplot(meas, aes(x = distance, y = value)) + geom_point(color = "red") + labs(title = "measured", x = "Distance (mm)")

grid.arrange(p.curve, p.meas, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

## The problem in practice

I want to find a mathematical/statistical method for R to fit `meas` to `curve` by changing the x-axis for `meas`. In addition I want to get some kind of goodness of fit statistics to compare the fitted "x-axes" among each other (in case I run several models with different constraints). I call the "x-axis model" a growth model, because that is what it essentially is. I want to constrain the fitting by specifying that distance between `meas` values has to be > 0. i.e. `Meas`value with `index == 2` has to occur after the value with `index == 1`. I also want to be able to constrain the growth rate (i.e. the maximum distance between two adjacent index points). To demonstrate this I will do it manually:

```
ggplot() + geom_line(data = curve, aes(x = index, y = value)) + geom_line(data = meas, aes(x = index, y = value), color = "red", linetype = 2) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,370,10)) + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(3,5,0.1))
```

[image]

First, some of the indices in `meas`(red dashed line) have to be anchored to the indices of `curve`(black line). I choose to anchor the first and the last point plus the point with the highest value.

```
anchor <- data.frame(meas.index = c(1,7,10), curve.index = c(11,215,367))

example.fit <- merge(meas, anchor, by.x = "index", by.y = "meas.index", all = T, sort = F)
example.fit <- example.fit[with(example.fit, order(distance)),]
```

Then, I assume a linear growth between these anchored points. The growth will be along `curve` indices. `Curve` has one value per day. Hence the growth will be on a daily scale.

```
library(zoo)
example.fit$curve.index <- round(na.approx(example.fit$curve.index),0)
```

After this I replace the indices with dates and plot the results.

```
library(plyr)

example.fit$date <- as.Date(mapvalues(example.fit$curve.index, from = curve$index, to = as.character(curve$date)))

a <- ggplot() + geom_line(data = curve, aes(x = date, y = value)) + geom_point(data = example.fit, aes(x = date, y = value), color = "red") + scale_x_date(limits = range(curve$date), name = "Month", breaks = date_breaks("months"), labels = date_format("%b"))

b <- ggplot(example.fit, aes(x = date, y = distance)) + geom_line() + scale_x_date(limits = range(curve$date), name = "Month", breaks = date_breaks("months"), labels = date_format("%b"))

grid.arrange(a,b)
```

[image]

The plot above shows the resulting fit, which is based on three anchor points. The plot below shows the modeled growth along time on daily interval. The bend in the growth curve in the beginning of March is some funny mathematical artifact I do not understand (due to `na.approx`function from [`zoo`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html) package).

## What have I tried

From [my previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78359/fitting-two-sets-of-values-by-changing-x-axis) I learned that [dynamic time warping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) could be a solution. I also found [an R package](http://dtw.r-forge.r-project.org), which contains dtw functions. Nice. Dynamic time warping, indeed, worked for my example dataset in that question (except for setting the constraint), but I cannot get it to work for this dataset, where `curve` has much more data points than `meas` (called `points` in the previous question). I will try to save some space and will not copy the code/figures here. You can see what I have tried in my answer to that question. The problem seems to be that none of the step patterns, except for the simplest one, can handle these type of data. The simplest step-pattern matches the measured values several times to the curve, which is something I want to avoid, because I need defined dates for each measurement point. Also setting the constraint that growth rate has to be >0 between measurement points seems difficult.

## Question

My question is two fold: first, **would there be a better method to solve the problem than dynamic time warping?** Second, **how do I do this in practice in R?**.

**EDITS** 9. Dec 2013 I tried to make the question clearer.

Comment: I'm not able to fully understand this question (e.g., what growth are you writing about?). I've been contemplating for a while now if that is my fault or if the question should be improved. I think it is a mixture of both. As it stands, your question can probably only be answered by specialists on the topic and it is unlikely that one of those drops in.

Comment: As @Roland pointed out, the question was not perhaps easy to understand. I do not know whether it is that now, but I tried to make it clearer.

Comment: @Largh It is dynamic time *warping*, not wrapping.

Comment: @nograpes Ok, fixed that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand 100% what the objective is, but if you're looking to fit the measured points to the reference curve then using `dtw` seems sensible. Fitting the 10 measured points to the 370-odd curve points does give a slightly strange result (which is just the optimization with the symmetric step.pattern). I think that's largely a function of the small number of points.

One option which may help is to use `ggplot()` (or another function) to smooth the measured curve and provide some additional points for matching. But obviously it can only do so much depending on the limitation of the measured points. With so few points you might lose information in the process of fitting your data.

If you could trim `curve` to be exactly contemporaneous with the first and last point of the `meas` observations, that would also help since you're matching with `open.begin` and `open.end` `FALSE`, but I'm not sure whether the exact dates are available.

This shows smoothing `meas` out to 80 points, and mapping the 10-point raw data and 80-point smooth to the reference `curve`

```
require(ggplot2)
require(scales)
require(gridExtra)
require(dtw)
require(plyr)

# use ggplot default to smooth the 10 point curve
meas.plot.smooth<-ggplot(meas, aes(x = distance, y = value)) + geom_line() + labs(title = "ggplot smoothed (blue curve)")+geom_smooth()
# use ggplot_build() to get the smoothed points
meas.curve.smooth<-ggplot_build(meas.plot.smooth)$data[[2]]

orig.align<-dtw(meas$value,curve$value,keep=T,step.pattern=symmetric1)
orig.freqs<-count(orig.align$index1)
# reference the matching points (which are effectively dates)
orig.freqs$cumsum<-cumsum(orig.freqs$freq)  

g.10<-ggplot() + geom_line(data = curve, aes(x = date, y = value)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = curve[orig.freqs$cumsum,"date"], y = meas$value),color="red") +
  geom_text(aes(x = curve[orig.freqs$cumsum,"date"], y = meas$value, label=orig.freqs$x),color="red",size=5) + 
  scale_x_date(name = "Month", breaks = date_breaks("months"), labels = date_format("%b")) + 
  labs(title = "Native 10 pt curve - dtw mapped")


smooth.align<-dtw(meas.curve.smooth$y,curve$value,keep=T,step.pattern=symmetric1)
smooth.freqs<-count(smooth.align$index1)
smooth.freqs$cumsum<-cumsum(smooth.freqs$freq)

g.80<-ggplot() + geom_line(data = curve, aes(x = date, y = value)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = curve[smooth.freqs$cumsum,"date"], y = meas.curve.smooth$y),color="red") +
  scale_x_date(name = "Month", breaks = date_breaks("months"), labels = date_format("%b")) + 
  geom_text(aes(x = curve[smooth.freqs$cumsum,"date"], y = meas.curve.smooth$y, label=smooth.freqs$x),color="red",size=3.5,position="jitter") + 
  labs(title = "80 point loess curve - dtw mapped")

grid.arrange(meas.plot.smooth,g.10,g.80,ncol=1)
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Obviously part of the problem is confidence intervals. I've included an example here to build a random curve within the standard error levels around the smoothed curve. As you can see, it's quite different to using the projected curve itself. I think the issue is that when you're trying to map 10 measures against a 370-point reference curve, unless they track *extremely* tightly, it's going to be difficult to get precise predictions.

```
rand.align<-dtw(meas.curve.smooth$ymin+(meas.curve.smooth$ymax-meas.curve.smooth$ymin)*runif(length(meas.curve.smooth$ymin)),curve$value,keep=T,step.pattern=symmetric1)
rand.freqs<-count(rand.align$index1)
rand.freqs$cumsum<-cumsum(rand.freqs$freq)

g.rand<-ggplot() + geom_line(data = curve, aes(x = date, y = value)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = curve[rand.freqs$cumsum,"date"], y = meas.curve.smooth$y),color="red") +
  scale_x_date(name = "Month", breaks = date_breaks("months"), labels = date_format("%b")) + 
  geom_text(aes(x = curve[rand.freqs$cumsum,"date"], y = meas.curve.smooth$y, label=rand.freqs$x),color="red",size=3.5,position="jitter") + 
  labs(title = "Random curve within standard CI - dtw mapped")

grid.arrange(meas.plot.smooth,g.10,g.80,g.rand,ncol=1)
```

[image]

**EDIT** updated to include simulation.

OK - this is updated to run 1000 simulations. It creates curves for mapping which are randomised from within the 95% CI. I changed n to 10 (from 80) in the `geom_smooth()` function to try and preserve as much info as possible from the measured curve.

It models the cumulative growth (assuming linear growth between unmeasured days)

Not sure if it's completely useful, but provides a decent way of visualizing the uncertainty.

```
get_scenario<-function(i){
  set.seed(i)
  # create random curve within the CI
  rand.align<-dtw(meas.curve.smooth$ymin+(meas.curve.smooth$ymax-meas.curve.smooth$ymin)*runif(length(meas.curve.smooth$ymin)),curve$value,keep=T,step.pattern=symmetric1)
  rand.freqs<-count(rand.align$index1)
  rand.freqs$cumsum<-cumsum(rand.freqs$freq)
  growth.index<-data.frame(cumsum=curve$index,val=curve$value)
  merged<-merge(growth.index,rand.freqs,by="cumsum")
  return(data.frame(x=merged$cumsum,growth=cumsum(merged$val*merged$freq),scenario=i))  
}

scenario.set <- ldply(lapply(1:1000,function(l)get_scenario(l)), data.frame)

g.s<-ggplot(scenario.set,aes(x,growth)) + 
      geom_line(aes(,group=scenario,color=scenario),alpha=0.25) + 
      scale_colour_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "orangered") +
      xlab("Days from start") + ylab("Cumulative Growth")
g.xmax<-max(scenario.set$x)  # get the final day (or set to another day)
g.xmin<-g.xmax-30            # thirty day window from end
b<-ggplot_build(g.s)
build.data<-b$data[[1]]
ylims<-build.data[build.data$x<=g.xmax & build.data$x>=g.xmin,]$y

g.subplot<-g.s+geom_point(aes(x,growth,color=scenario),alpha=0.25,size=5,position="jitter")+coord_cartesian(xlim=c(g.xmin,g.xmax),ylim=c(min(ylims),max(ylims)))

grid.arrange(meas.plot.smooth,g.s,g.subplot,ncol=1)
```

[image]

and here are some other ways of looking at the tail:

```
g.s<-ggplot(scenario.set,aes(x,growth)) + 
      geom_line(aes(,group=scenario,color=scenario),alpha=0.25) + 
      scale_colour_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "orangered") +
      xlab("Days from start") + ylab("Cumulative Growth")
g.xmax<-max(scenario.set$x)  # get the final day (or set to another day)
g.xmin<-g.xmax-50            # thirty day window from end
b<-ggplot_build(g.s)
build.data<-b$data[[1]]
ylims<-build.data[build.data$x<=g.xmax & build.data$x>=g.xmin,]$y

g.subplot<-g.s+geom_point(aes(x,growth,color=scenario),alpha=0.25,size=5,position="jitter")+coord_cartesian(xlim=c(g.xmin,g.xmax),ylim=c(min(ylims),max(ylims)))

grid.arrange(meas.plot.smooth,g.s,g.subplot,ncol=1)    

g.box<-ggplot(build.data)+
  geom_boxplot(aes(x,y,group=cut(x,max(x)/7),fill=cut(x,max(x)/7)),alpha=0.5)+ # bucket by group
  theme(legend.position="none")+
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(g.xmin,g.xmax),ylim=c(min(ylims)-50,max(ylims)+50))

build.data.sum<-ddply(build.data,.(x),summarise,ymax=max(y),ymin=min(y),mean=mean(y))

g.spots<-ggplot(build.data)+
  geom_point(aes(x,y,color=group),size=10,alpha=0.25,position="jitter")+
  theme(legend.position="none")+scale_colour_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "orangered")+
  geom_ribbon(data=build.data.sum,aes(x,ymax=ymax,ymin=ymin),alpha=0.25)+
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(g.xmax-50,g.xmax+1),ylim=c(min(ylims)-50,max(ylims)+50))+geom_smooth(aes(x,y),n=max(build.data$x))

grid.arrange(g.box,g.spots,ncol=1)
```

[image]

Comment: I am sorry that I did not respond this earlier. I had to think. This solution kind of works, but one have to somehow get the native points from the 80 point loess curve. It is the native points that need to be fitted, and their location has to be known. I will come back to this once I have had time to think more about it.

Comment: @Largh - updated to show a method for mapping random smooths of meas within the standard error range against the reference curve. As you can see, it can vary a lot, but maybe you can use something like this in a large simulation? I think the problem is that unless your growth tracks d18O almost exactly, it's going to be pretty tough to make an accurate prediction from just 10 points, no?

Comment: Thanks for the update! True. It is probably impossible to make an exact prediction. Rather one could come up with different scenarios. I was trying to look for ways to express uncertainty. Your solution is a good start. I´ll wait for a day or so and accept your answer unless someone comes up with something that solves the problem better.

Comment: @Largh I think scenario simulation might help - I'll have a think about an example and edit the answer.

Comment: Wow. An impressively detailed answer =) Probably it could be streamlined at places, but this definitely helps to get me started, and you deserve the points (and more!) for this answer. Thank you! I might post another answer here one day after my sessions with the real data, but that will take weeks or even months.

Comment: @Troy this is an impressively detailed (and patiently edited!) answer. Well done +1.